# How to load external CSS file with Pug

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to load a css file and an image into my pug file and neither are loading. It feels like I have tried everything I could find with no solution. I have my css and image in the public folder which is set as static with express. I appreciate any help I can get.

**The folder structure is as follows:**

```
server.js
views
  checklist.pug
routes
  checklist.js
public
  images
    logo.png
  stylesheets
    checklist.css
pdfs
```

**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const checklists = require('./routes/checklists');

const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// View engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Routes
app.use('/checklists', checklists);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}...`);
});
```

**checklist.pug**

```
html(lang='en')
    head
        link(href='stylesheets/checklist.css' rel='stylesheet')
        link(rel='preconnect' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com')
        link(rel='preconnect' href='https://fonts.gstatic.com' crossorigin)
        link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap' rel='stylesheet')
    body 

        div(class='checklist-title')
            img(src='images/logo.png' alt='Logo...')
```

**checklist.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const { v4 } = require('uuid');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const pug = require('pug');

const dynamodb_config = require('../config/dynamodb/dynamo_config');
aws.config.update(dynamodb_config);
const { validateChecklist } = require('../middleware/validation');
const authenticateToken = require('../middleware/authenticateToken');

const router = express.Router();
const docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const TABLE_NAME = 'Checklists';

// Generate html from checklist object, convert to pdf and send in response
router.get('/:id/pdf', authenticateToken, (req, res) => {
    // Get the checklist and make sure the user owns it
    const params = {
        TableName: TABLE_NAME,
        Key: {
            id: req.params.id
        }
    }
    docClient.get(params, async (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500);
            res.json({
                error: err
            });
        }
        else {
            // Check that an item was found
            if (typeof data.Item != 'undefined') {
                // An item was found
                // Check that the user who sent the request is the owner of the item
                if (req.username == data.Item.createdBy) {
                    // CODE TO GENERATE CHECKLIST HERE
                    try {
                        const checklist = {
                            checklist: data.Item
                        }
                        // render html
                        const compiledFunction = pug.compileFile('views/checklist.pug');
                        const htmlContent = compiledFunction(checklist);

                        // convert html to pdf and save file
                        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
                        const page = await browser.newPage();
                        await page.setContent(htmlContent, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
                        await page.pdf({ path: `pdfs/${req.username}.pdf`, printBackground: true });
                        await browser.close();

                        res.status(200);
                        res.json({
                            message: 'success'
                        });
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // User does not own the item
                    console.error('You are not authorized to access that item');
                    res.status(403);
                    res.json({
                        error: 'You are not authorized to access that item'
                    });
                }
            }
            else {
                // No item was found
                console.error(`A checklist with id ${req.params.id} could not be found`);
                res.status(404);
                res.json({
                    error: `A checklist with id ${req.params.id} could not be found`
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `link(href="/stylesheets/checklist.css" rel="stylesheet")`  and `img(src="/images/logo.png"` The `routes` folder is not mentioned in your folder structure. checklist.js is not shown.

Comment: Thanks @OldGeezer Unfortunately those changes to the paths did not solve it. Sorry for the missing information, I have updated the question with the folder structure of routes and I added the relevant info from checklist.js. Let me know what you think. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I think the issue could be with `puppeteer` of which I have no experience. It appears to be generating a html page from some file content, and is not getting from a web url. Therefore, the paths for sub-folders images and stylesheets have to be relative to the default folder that applies to the browser when `page.newPage()` is invoked. You may try experimenting to find that location, if it is not in the `puppeteer` documentation.

Comment: What the code is doing is first generating the html from the pug file and my database object, then loading that html into puppeteer (headless browser) and then I am essentially printing that browser page to pdf. The pdf folder is in the root of the project. I have updated my question to show that. That shouldnt change anything though as far as I understand. I think your point about the relative path for the browser may be on to something, but it's not immediately clear how I could test that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem ended up lying with puppeteer in the end like @OldGeezer said. Since I was using the page.setContent() function from puppeteer to load html content directly into the browser instead of giving it a path to an html file, neither of the relative paths to my image or css worked. How I ended up solving it was by using the page.goto(path) function in puppeteer to load an empty html file I created in the public folder and then using the page.setContent() function to load the html I wanted. This allowed the browser to be in the right directory to load the external files via their relative paths.

```
server.js
views
  checklist.pug
routes
  checklist.js
public
  empty.html
  images
    logo.png
  stylesheets
    checklist.css
pdfs
```

**checklist.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const { v4 } = require('uuid');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const pug = require('pug');

const dynamodb_config = require('../config/dynamodb/dynamo_config');
aws.config.update(dynamodb_config);
const { validateChecklist } = require('../middleware/validation');
const authenticateToken = require('../middleware/authenticateToken');

const router = express.Router();
const docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const TABLE_NAME = 'Checklists';

// Generate html from checklist object, convert to pdf and send in response
router.get('/:id/pdf', authenticateToken, (req, res) => {
    // Get the checklist and make sure the user owns it
    const params = {
        TableName: TABLE_NAME,
        Key: {
            id: req.params.id
        }
    }
    docClient.get(params, async (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500);
            res.json({
                error: err
            });
        }
        else {
            // Check that an item was found
            if (typeof data.Item != 'undefined') {
                // An item was found
                // Check that the user who sent the request is the owner of the item
                if (req.username == data.Item.createdBy) {
                    // CODE TO GENERATE CHECKLIST HERE
                    try {
                        const checklist = {
                            checklist: data.Item
                        }
                        // render html
                        const compiledFunction = pug.compileFile('views/checklist.pug');
                        const htmlContent = compiledFunction(checklist);

                        // convert html to pdf and save file
                        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
                        const page = await browser.newPage();

                        // go to empty html file
                        await page.goto('file://' + __dirname + '/../public/empty.html');

                        await page.setContent(htmlContent, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
                        await page.pdf({ path: `pdfs/${req.username}.pdf`, printBackground: true });
                        await browser.close();

                        res.status(200);
                        res.json({
                            message: 'success'
                        });
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // User does not own the item
                    console.error('You are not authorized to access that item');
                    res.status(403);
                    res.json({
                        error: 'You are not authorized to access that item'
                    });
                }
            }
            else {
                // No item was found
                console.error(`A checklist with id ${req.params.id} could not be found`);
                res.status(404);
                res.json({
                    error: `A checklist with id ${req.params.id} could not be found`
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```